# ampersand in php mail "FROM" header

Tags: php, forms, email, escaping

OK, I am stumped. I have a client with an ampersand in the company name. Like "Bill & Bob Associates". So, I have a from line like:

```
 $headers  = "From: Bill & Bob Associates, LLC <info@billbob.com>\r\n";
```

The & is breaking the from in the email like such;

```
From: info@host.webhost.com,
&@host.webhost.com, Associates@host.webhost.com,
LLC <info@billbob.com>
```

Tried %26 and that did not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried  to enclose the name in double quotes?

Comment: Try `&amp;`? Odd as it looks, that's the html entity for the ampersand, and may help the interpreter

Comment: @nanocv, close, the field was already in double quotes. So into itself, that would not work, but, it lead me to the answer, down below. THX

Answer (score 0):

could be like :

`$headers  = "From: ". mb_encode_mimeheader('Bill & Bob Associates, LLC', 'UTF-8', 'Q') ." <info@billbob.com>\r\n";`

or you could try:

`$headers = "From: =?UTF-8?B?". base64_encode('Bill & Bob Associates, LLC') 
               ."?= <info@billbob.com>\r\n"`

Comment: I tried this from your suggestion but same issue. Thx

Answer (score 0):

@nanocv was on the right track, but, the string was already in double quotes. But, going to a single quote, AND adding double quotes around the name did the trick, as in:

```
$headers    = 'From: "Bill & Bob, LLC" <ino@billbob.com>\r\n';
```

Which, now that I look at it, makes sense.